# How to reduce JSON response data to minimum

Tags: wcf, json, http

I Created WCF REST Service the following way:

```
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "StoreData/sid={SessionID}&Data={UserData}", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
        public string StoreData(string SessionID, string UserData)
        {
            string result = DBWorks.StoreUserData(SessionID, UserData);
            return result;
        }
```

The service is consumed by mobile device so in order to reduce the link cost I would like to sent as little data as possible. The service above returns the following:

```
.CONNECT

.HTTP/1.1 200 OK

.Content-Length: 4

.Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8

.Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0

.Date: Mon, 17 Oct 2011 23:25:55 GMT

.

."69"
```

The only relevant information from the axample above for mobile device is 69. Is it possible to modify the service such that any of other data from the example would not be sent?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since everything besides the `69` are the HTTP headers, I hardly see how this could be melted down further.

Answer (score 1):

The other lines are standard HTTP response headers (except maybe Date and Server).  Even if you could remove them, you shouldn't otherwise how will your client know whether the request was processed succesfully (200 OK), or not (e.g. 400 Bad Request)?